# AWS SES logs to Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

Currently I am using configuration sets with metrics dashboards for monitoring SES sending statistics. But I am wondering if it is possible to log send details from SES directly to Cloudwatch as normal logs, so I could later query them using log insights?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding this is possible. We are logging the email bounce details in the Amazon Cloud watch. For more information please follow the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-retrieving-cloudwatch.html